# Test if socket is open and listening, node, socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to know form a stand alone Node application if a remote server (running with Socket.io) is up and listening for incoming connections.

If the server is up and listening, then connect with socket-io.client, and if not, record something to a DB.

I don't know how to accomplish this with socket-io.client. The address has IP and Port, so I just can't ping to the IP without the port.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know the port number you want to see if it is listening on?

Comment: @jfriend00 I know the port and the IP, but you can't ping a port (or not that I know), just the IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just attempt to make a socket.io connection to the server.  If it succeeds, then it is listening.  If it fails, then apparently it is not listening.  Here's a way to do that:

```
// check a socket.io connection on another server from a node.js server
// can also by used from browser client by removing the require()
// pass hostname and port in URL form
// if no port, then default is 80 for http and 443 for https
// 2nd argument timeout is optional, defaults to 5 seconds
var io = require('socket.io-client');

function checkSocketIoConnect(url, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var errAlready = false;
        timeout = timeout || 5000;
        var socket = io(url, {reconnection: false, timeout: timeout});
        
        // success
        socket.on("connect", function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve();
            socket.close();
        });
        
        // set our own timeout in case the socket ends some other way than what we are listening for
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            timer = null;
            error("local timeout");
        }, timeout);
        
        // common error handler
        function error(data) {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            if (!errAlready) {
                errAlready = true;
                reject(data);
                socket.disconnect();
            }
        }
        
        // errors
        socket.on("connect_error", error);
        socket.on("connect_timeout", error);
        socket.on("error", error);
        socket.on("disconnect", error);
        
    });
}

checkSocketIoConnect("http://192.168.1.10:8080").then(function() {
    // succeeded here
}, function(reason) {
    // failed here
});
```

Comment: @Laerion - Did this answer your question?

Comment: The idea worked, I modified it a bit to suit my code, but I'm getting a `{
  "type": "TransportError",
  "description": 503
}` do you have any idea?

Comment: @Laerion - Wild guess.  [This report](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1995) sounds like it may be a mismatch in socket.io version between client and server.

Comment: Seven years old but I think there's a typo, it should be 443 for https, not 447.